# Your tips to learn regexp

Tags: regular-expression

I see a lot of members here manipulating and using regexp very easily. 
I am slowly learning, one trick at a time, how to search for this or that, how to handle this case, how to escape that case... But at this rate, it will take me ages before I can efficiently use VIM's regexp. I also tried to read the documentation, but all the small symbols/special characters are not the easiest to remember.

I am therefore asking if there is any kind of "regexp" tutorial you came across during your learning process.

I found [vimregex.com](http://vimregex.com/) that's already a very good start, but maybe some of you have even better / more interactive / easier answers ?

**Edit**
This question was put "on hold" for being "primarily opinion-based", which I understand. The few answers and comments I got however gave a few interesting tips, so I changed my question to the current one. 
I guess it's still opinion-based ? But maybe more useful this way ?

Comment: I learned POSIX regex from [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Learning-Perl-Randal-L-Schwartz/dp/1449303587?ie=UTF8&redirect=true&tag=develooper) and just picked up Viim's syntax over time. (Still learning some of the more complicated vim stuff like `\zs`)

Comment: You should post your question on https://www.reddit.com/r/vim.

Comment: Sometimes, it's not just the regexp (I think you learn it when you need it), but also regex and global/substitute/ex commands in combination. For this, I heartily recommend this tutorial (adapted to Vim): http://dahu.github.io/vim_waz_ere/
Regexp-wise, do learn Vim's specific matchers: `\zs`, `\ze`, they simplify substitution a lot.

Comment: Don't think that any answer with a regexp is made "very easily". I often have to muck about a bit and refer to the documentation! And I figure most people learned it the same way you're doing: "one trick at a time", and with quite a bit of effort...

Comment: It ultimately boils down to your learning style, but I'd personally recommend _against_ interactive regex mungers and the like. Rather, read the man page for [mawk(1)](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/manpage/mawk.html), it's one of the most well-written and to-the-point man pages.  Focus on concepts, not syntax.  When you're done you'll know `awk(1)`, which is tremendously useful by itself, and you'll have an easy time understanding the differences in syntax between `sed(1)`, `grep(1)`, `perl(1)`, `vim(1)` and so on.

Comment: I too learnt it here and there for different commands and languages, takes time to get used to.. and I know enough to know that there is plenty I do not know.. still what I have learnt is quite useful.. have a look at these links: What does this regex mean?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean , vim specific https://github.com/learnbyexample/vim_reference/blob/master/Regular_Expressions.md , https://regex101.com/ is quite handy too

Comment: Exactly what @Carpetsmoker said. In regard to the symbols not being easy to remember: the ones I regularly use are memorized. The rest is just remembered well enough to look up quickly. I don't think I'll ever memorize the details for all of the `\@` and `\%` atoms, but I have a general idea of what they do and can use `:h \@` to get me in the right spot of the docs quickly.

Comment: Also (the "zen" answer :P) - study this, line by line: http://zzapper.co.uk/vimtips.html (I didn't, and won't)

Answer (score 3):

Along with what everybody else said, I have a custom help file specifically for regex. Anytime I learn something that's useful, but might be hard to remember, I stick it in the help file. I can pull up this help file with a single keystroke and reference it whenever I need.

This way when you learn things it's not like trying you're trying to hold all your knowledge in a sieve. And as time goes on, you might be able to remove things from the help file because you've used them so much that you know them by heart. Ultimately it's a process that you're just going to have to go through, but this tool has helped me a LOT, so I thought I'd share it.